# Replace JSON values based on another JSON with same columns

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'm pretty new working with JSON files. I have two JSON Files that looks like this:

J1:

```
{'country': PA,
 'year': '2021',
 'month': '10',
 'client': 'x',
 'data': [{'id': 'g0084',
   'lat': y,
   'lon': q,
   'avg_audience': 87.84,
   'audiences': [{'day': '01', 'audience': 84},
    {'day': '02', 'audience': 83},
    {'day': '03', 'audience': 52},
     ...
    {'id': 'g0093',
     'lat': y,
     'lon': q,
     'avg_audience': 36.13,
     'audiences': [{'day': '01', 'audience': 48},
     {'day': '02', 'audience': 47},
     {'day': '03', 'audience': 39},
```

J2:

```
 [{'id': 'g0084', 'day': '01', 'audience': 190365.76367661008},
 {'id': 'g0084', 'day': '02', 'audience': 186712.00627779233},
 {'id': 'g0084', 'day': '03', 'audience': 161048.6891385768},
  ...
 {'id': 'g0093', 'day': '01', 'audience': 108780.43638663433},
 {'id': 'g0093', 'day': '02', 'audience': 105728.4854826053},
 {'id': 'g0093', 'day': '03', 'audience': 120786.51685393258},
```

So I want to replace the audience value in J1 with the audience value in J2. Based on the same ID and day. My desired output looks like this:

```
{'country': PA,
 'year': '2021',
 'month': '10',
 'client': 'x',
 'data': [{'id': 'g0084',
   'lat': y,
   'lon': q,
   'avg_audience': 87.84,
   'audiences': [{'day': '01', 'audience': 190365.76367661008}},
    {'day': '02', 'audience': 186712.00627779233},
    {'day': '03', 'audience': 161048.6891385768},
     ...
    {'id': 'g0093',
     'lat': y,
     'lon': q,
     'avg_audience': 36.13,
     'audiences': [{'day': '01', 'audience': 108780.4},
     {'day': '02', 'audience': 105728.48},
     {'day': '03', 'audience': 105728.48},
```

And I have no idea how to do this. Any help, please?

Comment: Convert J2 to nested dictionaries using id and day as keys. Then loop through J1, looking up the values to replace with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to do this, but I'd like to rant a bit first.  It seems that more and more people are using JSON for what rightly should be stored in a database.  This is one such example.  JSON was designed for data interchange, not for long-term storage.

But even if you don't use a database, the data structure here is not correct.  Why is `'data'` a list of objects, instead of being an object where `'id'` is the key?  Same with `audiences`.  That should not be a list of records, it should be an object where `'day'` is the key and `'audience'` is the value.  Those changes would have made this update trivial.  Indeed, if you had many thousands of records, I would probably create a dictionary index of J1 before beginning the update.

```
J1 = {'country': 'PA',
 'year': '2021',
 'month': '10',
 'client': 'x',
 'data': [
  {'id': 'g0084',
   'lat': 123.456,
   'lon': 123.456,
   'avg_audience': 87.84,
   'audiences': [{'day': '01', 'audience': 84},
    {'day': '02', 'audience': 83},
    {'day': '03', 'audience': 52},
    ]
  },
  {'id': 'g0093',
     'lat': 123.456,
     'lon': 123.456,
     'avg_audience': 36.13,
     'audiences': [{'day': '01', 'audience': 48},
     {'day': '02', 'audience': 47},
     {'day': '03', 'audience': 39}
     ]
  }
]
}

J2 = [
 {'id': 'g0084', 'day': '01', 'audience': 190365.76367661008},
 {'id': 'g0084', 'day': '02', 'audience': 186712.00627779233},
 {'id': 'g0084', 'day': '03', 'audience': 161048.6891385768},
 {'id': 'g0093', 'day': '01', 'audience': 108780.43638663433},
 {'id': 'g0093', 'day': '02', 'audience': 105728.4854826053},
 {'id': 'g0093', 'day': '03', 'audience': 120786.51685393258}
]

# Make an index into J1['data].

idx = {}
for row in J1['data']:
    idx[row['id']] = row

for row in J2:
    # Find the id.
    idx = [t for t in J1['data'] if t['id'] == row['id']][0]
    # Find the day.
    day = [t for t in idx['audiences'] if t['day'] == row['day']][0]
    day['audience'] = row['audience']

from pprint import pprint
pprint(J1)
```

Output:

```
{'client': 'x',
 'country': 'PA',
 'data': [{'audiences': [{'audience': 190365.76367661008, 'day': '01'},
                         {'audience': 186712.00627779233, 'day': '02'},
                         {'audience': 161048.6891385768, 'day': '03'}],
           'avg_audience': 87.84,
           'id': 'g0084',
           'lat': 123.456,
           'lon': 123.456},
          {'audiences': [{'audience': 108780.43638663433, 'day': '01'},
                         {'audience': 105728.4854826053, 'day': '02'},
                         {'audience': 120786.51685393258, 'day': '03'}],
           'avg_audience': 36.13,
           'id': 'g0093',
           'lat': 123.456,
           'lon': 123.456}],
 'month': '10',
 'year': '2021'}
```